# UTC timestamp in milliseconds c#

Tags: c#

Как это получить? Нашел `DateTime.Now.Ticks`, но это что-то не то.

Нужно именно UTC timestamp in milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вы хотите `Unix timestamp` (количество миллисекунд, которое прошло с 1970 года). Тогда ответ будет такой:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```